# How do I add a bot to a Skype groupchat thru skype api

Tags: botframework, skype, skype-bots

I created a bot.
Then I have to add it to my contact manually before I can add it into a group.

Is there any way I can add this bot to a group through skype api ? I just can't find it nowhere.

What I want is, using the api with param like group_ip so the bot will be added to the group automatically.

Comment: Do you want to make your bot automatically be added to particular group? If yes,  I personally think it's not a good design cause users may not like this behavior, why you want to do this? For the bot channel part, we can only enable/ disable our bot adding to a group.

Comment: @GraceFeng Yes, the bot needs to be in certain group so the bot can send messages to those group member from time to time.

Comment: @GraceFeng  Hmm.. I'm thinking, maybe what I really want, is not a bot. I'm not sure about it. Is there any way to send a message to a groupchat using skype api? I don't care if it's sent by a actual skype user account or microsoft bot ...